# ALL and empty set = TRUE

Tags: postgresql

If subquery that is in ALL opertar like (ALL (some subquery)) return empty set then it will be always return TRUE. Like that: SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE TRUE = ALL (empty set). How to change this conduct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subquery in:

```
ALL (SELECT ...)
```

returns the empty set, the result is `NULL`:

```
regress=> select all( SELECT true WHERE false );
 bool 
------

(1 row)
```

If you want true, you must use `coalesce`. You can't use `all` directly as an expression due to syntax limitations, you must wrap it in a subquery, like:

```
regress=> select coalesce( (select all( SELECT true WHERE false )), true);
 coalesce 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```